# How do you count the number of bits in an image after compression through DCT?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dct

I need to know how to enumerate the number of bits in an image (in MATLAB) after applying the DCT algorithm (compressing the image) to an image, I need to see the number of bits of an image after applying the DCT algorithm. Because I am applying it to a 512 x 512 image but I am getting the same number of bit before and after compression was wondering is there any Matlab code which calculates the number of bits for an image.

Comment: The DCT by itself negatively compresses. It takes more bites to represent the DCT coefficients than the original data.

Answer (score 1):

DCT is transform, not compression. No information is lost after applying it to input signal.

Normaly, algorithms like jpg, after DCT transform applies quantization of DCT coefficients to reduce amount of data. After then quantized coefficients arę compressed using huffman or other lossless compression algorithm.

So DCT is not able to say how many bits you are going to have after. You should ask huffman.

Comment: When you apply thresholding does it not decrease number of bits ?

Comment: Nope, its like rounding real number to integer. Both can occupy same amount of bits.

Comment: This is 100% correct. +1.  @user3197976 - Your question is asking about how much storage an image takes when performing the DCT.  The DCT is solely a transform.  **Quantization** will reduce the number of bits, not the DCT.  Because of this, the duplicate that was suggested is what your answer is.  Unless you modify your question to ask what you really want, this question will remain closed.

Answer (score 0):

The DCT algorithm itself does not reduce the size of the image matrix.
It applies a transform to the spatial domain matrix input, and outputs a 
matrix in the frequency domain. See this for a more detailed explanation.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/discrete-cosine-transform.html#f21-16149

Depending on the number of DCT coefficients discarded, which dictates the amount
of compression you are applying, the remaining non-zero coefficients tells you how
many bits remains. The number of bits per coefficient is determined by the class of
the image X.

e.g.
class(X)

ans = 
double

double is 64 bit
single is 32 bit